# How to update SuperGrid after changing dataSource

Tags: c#, user-interface, datagrid, datasource, dotnetbar

In `SuperGridControl` from [DevComponents](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/SuperDataGridControl.aspx) how can I update GUI after e.g. adding new row to the data source (`List<MyCustomObject>`). I'm sure this element is added (counter is increasing) but no changes are visible.

I'm trying

```
superGrid.PrimaryGrid.InvalidateLayout();
superGrid.PrimaryGrid.InvalidateRender();
superGrid.Refresh();
superGrid.Invalidate();
superGrid.Update();
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BindingList<>` instead of `List<>` solved this problem

Comment: Unfortunately it's solution only if you can change collection's class. Well designed grids have separate method to rebuild UI of items.